# Performing two query at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using php platform and I got a form, which allows the user to fill in the class name to create a class. However, at the same time, I need him to choose the students he wanted to add into the class. Is there a way to do this? Creating a class and adding students to class at the same time.

Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: Sure there is the way. What have you already tried?

Comment: I think you're looking for [joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

Comment: Have you tried inserting class in `Class` table if not exist, then take this id and insert into `Student_Class` table ?

Comment: You take the ID of the class, all of the ID's of the student's that the person selected, and then use a foreach to insert into Student_Class. Foreach student, insert the student_id and use the same class_id.